# Bring back changes made locally after a git revert

Tags: git

I needed to revert my commit that was merged into mainline due to a failed test. I used `git revert commitID` to revert my changes. But now all the changes made are also gone from my local, how do I get the changes back locally so I can modify it and send out a new Code Review?

Comment: `git revert` created a new commit (probably it is still HEAD).  Go to the commit before it with `git checkout HEAD~1`

Comment: @WilliamPursell that worked, but now when I do ```git status``` I don't see the files that I had changed previously, so if I do make new changes and want to raise a new Code review, how would I obtain all the files that I have changed?

Comment: To see a status of your files with respect to the previous commit: try `git diff --name-status HEAD~`. To view the diff of a specific file: `git diff HEAD~ -- that/specific/file`. You can also try: `git difftool -d HEAD~`.